# Can DFS replicate across WAN?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dfs, wide-area-network

I've got 3 servers

DC and File server 1 in one location
File Server 2 in another location

They are all connected to the domain, and running DFS.

When I set up a replication group and try and include File Server 2, it says the network path is not found.  Have I missed something?  I'm sure this should be possible

Comment: Yes it's certainly possible. Do you have a VPN in place between your sites? Are all of the relevant network ports open and able to traverse the VPN?

Comment: I have no Vpn...is this a requirement? It looked like it was possible without.  Firewal is all correct

Comment: Well yes, DFS will require VPN. If you don't have VPN at the moment, how is File Server 2 connected to the domain?

Answer (score 3):

You need a VPN connecting your two sites.

DFS relies on several ports being open between member servers, none of which have any business travelling unencrypted over the internet.

[This page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832017#method8) details what ports are required for DFS Namespace communication and DFS Replication.

Comment: I did a bit more research, and turns out you can do it without a VPN...it just uses RPC encrpyption, but it is possible